# How do I know which tensions are available?

Tags: theory, harmony

Given a diatonic chord in a scale, what are the rules to find out which tensions among 9, 11#, 13, I can use?

Comment: What rules? For the umpteenth time - there is theory, there are no rules!! Ears work best her4e. Listen carefully, and like/dislike what you hear. Use/don't use.

Comment: If everything boils down to our ears, that would make this entire site obsolete.

Comment: There are rules, it just depends on which genre you intend to play in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By counting up the Major scale, you'll find the 9th, 11th, and 13th notes that make up the 9th, 11th, and 13th chords. If you look at a Major 13th chord you can see that it also contains the 7th, 9th, and 11th notes in the chord. This is the way that any diatonic extension is made on a chord in "theory". However, in practice, it is not necessary to include all of these notes. The important note is the 7th. If you have C-E-G-B-A, you have enough notes to imply a C Major 13 chord. If you take away the 7th, you end up with C-E-G-A, a C6 chord. You can extend Major, minor, and Dominant Chords. Chromatic alterations occur most frequently in chords having a flatted 7th note - chords in the Dominant family.

Comment: This is explained very clearly in common language in writings by Leon White

Comment: I think that the OP's question is a little bit under-specified. Note that a diatonic IV chord might have a ♯11 in it (**FMaj7(♯11)** in C Major), or a iii chord might have a ♭9 in it (**E-7(♭9)** in C Major).

Comment: @David Bowling- It is my understanding that these chords are referred to as "chromatic alterations" as opposed to chord extensions, and you're probably correct about the post being under-specified. I just went with the extensions mentioned. Oops, I just noticed the raised 11th.

Comment: I've Just edited my answer to include some guidelines about chromatic extensions

Answer (score 1):

And don't forget the 7th!

Well, you probably don't want to clash too closely with the melody.  And you should consider the harmonic density - a b9#11 chord can sound a bit odd when surrounded with plain triads.

Above all, try not to see chords as seperate entities, but as a combination of melodic lines.

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb, an interval of a b9 between any two chord notes usually is considered too dissonant.

For major chords, available tensions are 9, #11 or 13.
For minor chords, available tensions are 9, 11 or 13.
For dominant chords, available tensions are any 9, #11, b13 or 13.

As always, music theory can be considered recommendations. Needless to say, if b9's really rock your boat then you will not get arrested for using them.